# Compile errors in Tensorflow Lite Micro framework when trying to integrate Tensorflow Lite Micro to my ESP32 Arduino project

Tags: c++, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, esp32, arduino-esp32

Hi stackoverflow community,

I am trying to get a project leveraging Tensorflow Lite Micro to run on my ESP32 using PlatformIO and the Arduino framework (not ESP-IDF). Basically, I followed the guide in this medium post https://towardsdatascience.com/tensorflow-meet-the-esp32-3ac36d7f32c7 and then included everything in my already existing ESP32 project.

My project was compiling fine prior to the integration of Tensorflow Lite Micro but since integrating it, I am getting the following compile errors which seem to be related to the Tensorflow framework itself. When I uncomment everything related to Tensorflow, it compiles fine. But just when only including the following header files, it breaks:

```
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/kernels/micro_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_mutable_op_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/version.h"
```

Does someone know where these errors come from and what I can do to solve those?

Here is the error trace:

```
In file included from /Users/XXX/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFiClient.h:24:0,
                 from /Users/XXX/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/libraries/WiFi/src/WiFi.h:37,
                 from src/main.cpp:3:
/Users/XXX/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:64:17: error: expected identifier before numeric constant
 #define DEFAULT 1
                 ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFAULT'
     DEFAULT = 1,
     ^
/Users/XXX/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:64:17: error: expected '}' before numeric constant
 #define DEFAULT 1
                 ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFAULT'
     DEFAULT = 1,
     ^
/Users/XXX/.platformio/packages/framework-arduinoespressif32/cores/esp32/Arduino.h:64:17: error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant
 #define DEFAULT 1
                 ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:31:5: note: in expansion of macro 'DEFAULT'
     DEFAULT = 1,
     ^
In file included from lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h:24:0,
                 from src/main.cpp:12:
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:51:21: error: declaration of '~tflite::Profiler' as non-member
   virtual ~Profiler() {}
                     ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:61:48: error: 'EventType' has not been declared
   virtual uint32_t BeginEvent(const char* tag, EventType event_type,
                                                ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:63:54: error: 'virtual' outside class declaration
                               int64_t event_metadata2) = 0;
                                                      ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:63:58: error: function 'uint32_t tflite::BeginEvent(const char*, int, int64_t, int64_t)' is initialized like a variable
                               int64_t event_metadata2) = 0;
                                                          ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:65:40: error: 'EventType' has not been declared
   uint32_t BeginEvent(const char* tag, EventType event_type,
                                        ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:74:48: error: 'virtual' outside class declaration
                         int64_t event_metadata2) {}
                                                ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:76:46: error: 'virtual' outside class declaration
   virtual void EndEvent(uint32_t event_handle) = 0;
                                              ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:76:50: error: function 'void tflite::EndEvent(uint32_t)' is initialized like a variable
   virtual void EndEvent(uint32_t event_handle) = 0;
                                                  ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:85:34: error: 'EventType' has not been declared
   void AddEvent(const char* tag, EventType event_type, uint64_t start,
                                  ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h: In function 'void tflite::AddEvent(const char*, int, uint64_t, uint64_t, int64_t)':
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:88:35: error: too many arguments to function 'void tflite::AddEvent(const char*, int, uint64_t, uint64_t, int64_t)'
              /*event_metadata2*/ 0);
                                   ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:85:8: note: declared here
   void AddEvent(const char* tag, EventType event_type, uint64_t start,
        ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h: At global scope:
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:91:42: error: 'EventType' has not been declared
   virtual void AddEvent(const char* tag, EventType event_type, uint64_t start,
                                          ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:93:48: error: 'virtual' outside class declaration
                         int64_t event_metadata2) {}
                                                ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:95:2: error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'
  protected:
  ^
lib/tfmicro/tensorflow/lite/core/api/profiler.h:105:25: error: expected ')' before '*' token
   ScopedProfile(Profiler* profiler, const char* tag,
                         ^
src/main.cpp:202:1: error: expected '}' at end of input
 }
 ^
src/main.cpp:202:1: error: expected unqualified-id at end of input
*** [.pio/build/esp32cam/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
```

Comment: OK for now I have solved this issue by switching to the ESP-IDF framework. With this, I get it to run without any problems. But I think the resolution of this issue might still be interesting for others who run into this issue using the Arduino framework with their ESP32.

Comment: Hello @the_smart_home_marker, is it possible to make this question as resolved (or adding an accepted answer?)

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj yes, I can do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this for now by switching from the Arduino framework to the ESP-IDF framework. With this, it works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Today I faced a similar problem. I solved it by using TensorFlowLite_ESP32 library instead of Arduino_TensorFlowLite. You need to download this library and add the line #include <TensorFlowLite_ESP32.h>. I hope this helps you too

Answer (score 2):

I've also faced the same issue. The issue is due the the lack of ESP32 library  dependency .
You can resolve the problem by adding "**#include <TensorFlowLite_ESP32.h>**" as the top-most header file.

```
#include <TensorFlowLite_ESP32.h>
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/all_ops_resolver.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_error_reporter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/micro_interpreter.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/micro/system_setup.h"
#include "tensorflow/lite/schema/schema_generated.h"
```

Also make sure that you have downloaded **TensorFlowLite ESP32** from library section